# Regex Get Number In Between Word & Digits

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
[Tag|String|WORD012311120151218]
```

How can I get `0123111` from `WORD012311120151218` - the problem I'm having is that `0123111` is dynamic and can come through the system as any length.

My thought process is as follows but I can't seem to get it right after searching: extract any value from after `WORD` and ends before the date `20151218` - the date changes daily but it's always going to be 8 digits.

Is this possible?

Comment: Which programming language or regular-expression engine are you using?  That will affect the specific syntax.  (And welcome to the site!  Check out the tour at http://stackoverflow.com/tour for info and a badge. :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
.*WORD(\d+)\d{8}\].*
```

And get the group `$1`.
Explanation in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/pK2cX0/2).

In Java, it would be:

```
String input = "[Tag|String|WORD012311120151218]";
String num = input.replaceAll(".*WORD(\\d+)\\d{8}\\].*", "$1");
System.out.println(num); //prints 0123111
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\[.*WORD([0-9]+)[0-9]{8,8}\]$/
```

should do it, with suitable escapes depending on which regex flavor you're using.  `([0-9]+)` is what you want, and `[0-9]{8,8}` is 8 trailing digits for the date.

Comment: Shorter version: `WORD(\d+)\d{8}`

Answer (score 0):

'WORD012311120151218'.match(/(\d+)(\d{8}$)/)[1]